# Best way to GROUP BY id while SELECTing a description field without including it in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have two tables:

Company Table

```
Id,
CompanyName
```

Sale Table:

```
Id,
CompanyId,
Date,
Value
```

I need to group sales by date and by company and display it like this:

```
CompanyId  CompanyName           Date        Value
---------  --------------------  ----------  --------
        1  Company 1             2021-10-01  2832.98
        2  Company 2             2021-10-01  8112.81
        1  Company 1             2021-10-02  2182.12
        2  Company 2             2021-10-02  3521.11
```

I know I can easily achieve it with this

```
SELECT s.CompanyId, c.CompanyName, s.Date, SUM(s.Value) FROM Sale s
JOIN Company c on s.CompanyId = c.Id
GROUP BY s.Date, s.CompanyId, c.CompanyName
```

The problem is that when I include `CompanyName` in the GROUP BY clause, it gets an order of magnitude slower. I may be able to circunvent it by adding a new index, but that's not an option right now.

I was able to make it run faster using this query

```
SELECT 
    s.CompanyId, 
    (SELECT CompanyName FROM Company WHERE Id = s.CompanyId) as CompanyName
    s.Date, 
    SUM(s.Value) 
FROM Sale s
GROUP BY s.Date, s.CompanyId
```

But I want to know if there's a faster/better method. The group by without the `CompanyName` runs in 2 seconds, If I add `CompanyName` to the GROUP BY it adds 20 seconds to the query. Using the last query I listed, it runs in around 5 seconds.

Comment: Without info on indexing, and a query plan (you can share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan) we can't help you. You're unlikely to improve the performance more than you already have without better indexing

Comment: You might try adding a *row goal* to your subquery which might help depending on what the current execution plan is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

defer the lookup of name until after the grouping?
Not tested...

```
select i.CompanyId,c.CompanyName,i.Date,i.Value
From Company c join(
SELECT 
    s.CompanyId, 
    s.Date, 
    SUM(s.Value) as [Value]
FROM Sale s
GROUP BY s.Date, s.CompanyId) i
on i.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
```

Comment: That's probably going to have the same performance as the subquery option. The engine is indeed usually clever enough to transform between the two

Comment: Aye too hard to tell from here, you'd hope then engine could figure this out as its a bit obvious. Index is the only real solution.

Comment: I would also think this should yield the same speed, but it's actually a bit faster. My query is a lot more complicated than what I showed you, I simplified it to focus on the problem. I'll accept you answer, thank you.

Comment: Since you already have CompanyId - couldn't you just use MAX(c.CompanyName)?